# How to make the node author's email show up as a replacement token in a Rules Action?

Tags: rules, emails, tokens

I have set up a rule that is as follows:

- **Rules Event**: After saving new content of type Article.
- **Rules Conditions**: User has role(s), with role = Authenticated user.
- **Rules Actions**: Send mail to all users of a role, with role = Administrator.

When anyone adds an article to the site, all the admins are notified and I have used token replacements for the email fields like so:

- **Mail Subject:** [node:author] has just created a piece of content entitled "[node:title]"
- **Message Body:**

  [node:author] has just created a piece of content entitled "[node:title]"

  You can see the article here and proof read: [node:edit-url]

  The article is here: [node:url]

This all works perfectly, however I want to also add the author of the node into this email so that any of the admins can email this person if they need to. I cannot work out how to get the author's email into the email body as it doesn't seem to show up in replacement patterns.

Anyone any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not listed among the replacement tokens, but you can use the [node:author:mail] token.

Answer (score 1):

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module is great, but it also has its hidden features ... ***Yes*** the "*token for the eMail Id of the node author*" is available to use it in the Rules Action (as in this question here). However you won't find it by simply expanding the typical "**`REPLACEMENT PATTERNS`**"-link that show up by default.

Instead, whenever you're looking for some token that at first doesn't seem to be available, you should try to use the <kbd>Switch to data selection</kbd> button as in this screenprint:

[image]

Then select "`node...(Created content)`" from the **Data selector** selection list (or if you know part of what you're looking for just start typing "`node:`"). After doing so, the list of possible values (= tokens starting with "`node:`") will change and start to show (dozens of) other values such as:

- `node:nid (Node ID)`
- `node:type (Content Type)`
- `node:author... (Node Author)`
- `node:comment (Comments allowed)`
- `node:comments... (Comments)`

In the above list, note the ones that have a "`...`": those are the ones that, after you select any of them, will bring up yet another list of tokens that start with what you selected. So if you select "`node:author... (Node Author)`", it'll show (many) other values (some with yet another "`...`"), such as:

- `node:author:uid (User ID)`
- `node:author:name (Name)`
- `node:author:mail (Email)`
- `node:author:roles... (User roles)`

So there you are: using the drill-down approach as shown above, `node:author:mail (Email)` is what you're looking for. All that's needed now, is to select it from this list. Though in this case there is no more *Label* and *Description* for the token, you only have what's shown between "`(`" and "`)`" to decide about which token to select.

PS: If you don't find what you're looking for (after using the <kbd>Switch to data selection</kbd> button), you can always return to the previous display by using the <kbd>Switch to the direct input mode</kbd> button.